# configure already deployed yocto build / flashing os with wifi

Tags: yocto, flash-memory, imx6, nxp-microcontroller, cortex-a

I got my hands on an already deployed yocto system (yocto 2.6.2 - thud) on a board with a NXP i.MX 6UL Cortex-A7. My only possible access at the moment is via wifi. I have access as root via wifi with ssh. The board is embedded into a case which I can't open. So no physical access to that board - just wifi.

My further intention is to setup/deploy/flash my own OS (yocto/debian/etc.) onto this board, but I have no proper knowledge to do so...

Is it even possible to flash a new image only with wifi access?

Which step is the next one I should consider?

Are there any documentations to start with?

Thanks

Comment: As I understand you have a working yocto system on the board and you want to update it via wifi?

Comment: yes update or „reflash“ with a new yocto build. The whole development section rely on a SDcard/debug-port and I dont have this

Comment: The complete ready solution doesn't exist. I'll describe to you how to develop it using ready parts in the answer.

Comment: amazing. I could find out that the built-in board is a variscite DART-6UL. So probably I need a customboard from variscite to do more. I just though if I‘m logged in as root via ssh I should be able to install packages etc… but it seems the whole yocto is far out of my experience. My intention was to reflash the board with OpenWRT - because it has all the functions I need. I did it already with a Raspi3+ but I had a SDcard to boot from.

Comment: The yocto doesn't work in such a way you can't install packets on a working system. You don't have a packet manager like in desktop OS. You need to add all necessary packets before compilation.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I mention that you have the **Variscite DART-6UL** module. The producer of your module provides a wiki with lots of information and tutorials on how to start work with. [Variscite DART-6UL Wiki](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=DART-6UL)

1. [How to build your yocto system](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Build_Release&release=RELEASE_DUNFELL_V1.1_DART-6UL)
2. Ready solution for update - [SWUpdate Guide](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=SWUpdate_Guide&release=RELEASE_DUNFELL_V1.1_DART-6UL)

Using SWUpdate is the easiest way to achieve updates for your module.

3. Custom solution:

Another way is to develop your own mechanism. In this case, you can do developed all processes and make them fully automatic, but it is complicated and required knowledge and experience.

4. For development boot from the server

For the development time, it can be useful to use booting from TFTP/NFS server. [More information here](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Setup_TFTP/NFS)

Other help sources:

- [Yocto Project - System Update](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/System_Update)
- [SWUpdate: software update for
  embedded system](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html)
- [Updating Embedded Linux Devices: SWUpdate](https://mkrak.org/2018/01/26/updating-embedded-linux-devices-part2)

Comment: thanks kluszon. I have already read parts of them. Unfortunately they want during the sections a sdcard or serial connection - I only have wifi. I also thought with TFTP/NFS I could rebuild the system, but they force me again to have a serial connection to the target and also want to interrupt the autoboot (I'm not able to do this cause I have to wait until wifi started ... ) But I give it a try with the SWUpdate documentation.

Comment: In the beginning, you need to prepare your yocto system using some devkit and then in the future, you can update it via wifi. It's not possible to flash the module without the correct configuration using some default/demo system.